# Best books and PDF resources about "Numerical solutions of differential equations"

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, book-recommendation

> What are the best books about  *"Numerical solutions of differential equations"* . I am looking for a free / paid books or PDF resources.

I need the best books to get master degree.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean ordinary differential equations or partial differential equations? Or both?

Comment: Is there a book for all of them? @MathOverview

Comment: There is not a such book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Numerical Analysis by Cheney and Kincaid](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847880) is a pretty good survey of numerical mathematics in general, and includes the basics of ODE and PDE solution at a beginning graduate level.

[Introduction to Numerical Methods in Differential Equations by Holmes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387308911) is a more focused text, and as such is much shorter. There's no fluff here though; it gets right into solve ODEs in the first 2 chapters and PDEs in the remaining 4.

[Finite Difference Methods by Leveque](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898716292) is another book focusing solely on numerical solution of ODEs and PDEs, but is much longer and more comprehensive. As the title implies, it has a heavy focus on finite difference methods.

Comment: İs it possible to find PDF free version?

Comment: I don't believe there are free, legal PDF versions of these texts online. However, if you look hard enough you can find anything...